# Where to set the the CreatedOn property of an Entity before inserting in database

Tags: entity-framework, repository

Say I have an entity as follows:

Restaurant

- Id : int
- Name : string
- CreatedOn : datetime (when it was added to the DB)

and I have a **RestaurantService** and **RestaurantRepository** classes. Both of these classes have an **AddRestaurant** method. The RestaurantService class does some work on the entities and then passes the entities to the repository for persistance.

Which of the two classes should be in charge of setting the **CreatedOn** property?

Should the repository be in charge of setting the **CreatedOn** property or should that be part of the Service class responsibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would personally put it as close to the database as possible - including actually in the database, if that meets your needs. Otherwise, though, wherever is closest to the point where it is actually persisted, because that's what is meant by `CreatedOn` in the first place.

Comment: I've always been a little afraid of delegating to the database the resposibility of the CreatedOn column. What if the database is in a different time zone than the application server? That might be a field that the user gets to see, and will find it weird that something that was just created is off by X hours.

Comment: It is customary to use UTC in cases where time zones are important. But that's fine; there are different reasons why having the DB do it might not be desired. In that case, I'd do it as close to the code that inserts the record as possible.

Answer (score 0):

As the record is persisted eventually by the Database itself, it makes sense to instruct the database to generate the current date whenever an entity is added.

You can configure that in Entity without touching the database. For example in Entity Framework 7 (the latest as per RC1)

Say I have an entity

```
public class Review
{
    public int ReviewId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
}
```

then in my context class, on model creating, I instantiate the mapping (I could do the mapping there, but I like to keep it separated)

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options ) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
    //etc.

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        //Mappings
        new ReviewMap(modelBuilder.Entity<Review>());
        //etc..
    }
}
```

and then the mapping. (Remember to use the namespace where the Model extensions are). In the instruction below I tell Entity that this value is generated when adding records (entities) and that the application does not need to manually set the datetime. Instead I tell it to execute the SQL Server function `GETUTCDATE()` when adding an entity so I don't need to worry about that anymore.

```
using Microsoft.Data.Entity; //here is where the extensions are
public class ReviewMap
{
    public ReviewMap(EntityTypeBuilder<Review> entityBuilder)
    {
        entityBuilder.HasKey(r => r.ReviewId);

        entityBuilder.Property(r => r.CreatedOn)
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
            .HasDefaultValueSql("GETUTCDATE()")
            .IsRequired(true);
    }
}
```

About your concern about database time zone, the good practice is to ALWAYS save dates as UTC in database (location agnostic) and transform the date as per the user location so the user always sees local date. That's why the instruction for the database is `GETUTCDATE()` rather than `GETDATE()`